# Angular project compiling with error: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Tags: angular, webpack, dojo

I'm currently trying to call Dojo inside an Angular project, I have this test code as followed

```
 /// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/dojo-typings/dojo/1.11/index.d.ts" />
    /// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/dojo-typings/dojo/1.11/modules.d.ts" />

    import * as lang from 'dojo/_base/lang';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MdCardModule} from '@angular/material';
    import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
    import { TaskService } from '../../services/task.service';
    import { Globals } from '../../global';
```

and somewhere in the component I call

```
console.log(lang.extend);
```

but when compiling the project, there are a lot of warnings and the page could not show, errors like

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/dojo/_base/kernel.js
79:39-46 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
    at CommonJsRequireContextDependency.getWarnings (/Users/dongming/work/hallmark/desktop/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/CommonJsRequireContextDependency.js:27:4)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/dongming/work/hallmark/desktop/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:694:24)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/dongming/work/hallmark/desktop/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:552:9)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/dongming/work/hallmark/desktop/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:512:17)
    at /Users/dongming/work/hallmark/desktop/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/dongming/work/hallmark/desktop/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:498:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/dongming/work/hallmark/desktop/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:468:14)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I feel like it's because the webpack could not find the dependencies due to configurations in package.json or tsconfig.json, but I'm quite new to Angular and could not figure out why. Could someone please shed some light on it?

Here is the package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "brace": "^0.10.0",
    "dojo": "^1.10.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ibm-design-colors": "^2.0.3",
    "ibm-design-icons": "^2.1.2",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.10.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "dojo-util": "1.12.2",
    "dojo-loader": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "dojo-typings": "^1.11.9",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.1.1",
    "dojo-webpack-plugin": "2.1.3",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom", "scripthost"  ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "and",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/*",
    "../node_modules/dojo-typings/dojo/1.11/modules.d.ts",
    "../node_modules/dojo-typings/dijit/1.11/modules.d.ts",
    "../node_modules/dojo-typings/dojox/1.11/modules.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get it all, but IMHO it seems you're doing something you shouldn't do that way..

- I wouldn't use the *reference* tag at the top of your file since you have typescript > 2
- Try installing [@types/dojo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dojo) : `npm i --save-dev @types/dojo` or other [dojo @types](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=@dojo&page=1&ranking=optimal)
- You may not need to include them in your `tsconfig.json`

It should be more straightforward after this